# How Session is maintain in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, session, service

I have a WCF project. I want to implement session in my project.

How is session maintained by BasicHttpBinding and NetTcpBinding?

Answer (score 1):

A session-based binding supports the default association of a service instance with a particular session. However, different session-based bindings support different features in addition to enabling the session-based instancing control previously described.

WCF provides the following types of session-based application behavior:

- The System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement supports
  security-based sessions, in which both ends of communication have
  agreed upon a specific secure conversation. For more information, see
  Securing Services. For example, the `System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding`
  binding, which contains support for both security sessions and
  reliable sessions, by default uses only a secure session that
  encrypts and digitally signs messages.
- The `System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding` binding supports TCP/IP-based
  sessions to ensure that all messages are correlated by the connection
  at the socket level.
- The `System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableSessionBindingElement`
  element, which implements the WS-ReliableMessaging specification,
  provides support for reliable sessions in which messages can be
  configured to be delivered in order and exactly once, ensuring
  messages are received even when messages travel across multiple nodes
  during the conversation. For more information, see Reliable Sessions.
- The `System.ServiceModel.NetMsmqBinding` binding provides MSMQ datagram
  sessions. For more information, see Queues in Windows Communication
  Foundation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183865.aspx

Comment: Where does session store?

Comment: If you host the WCF service in IIS and enable ASP compatibility mode, you can use the full functionalities of ASP.NET session state, including InProc, SqlServer or StateServer modes to handle state persistence.  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234(v=vs.110).aspx